# Who was watching Walt outside his house in season 2?

Tags: breaking-bad

In this video from *Breaking Bad*

Walt starts off with:

"How would he know where I live?" (referring to someone in a car outside his house earlier)

Is it ever revealed who was in this car, if it was Tuco or if Walt was just being paranoid?

Comment: I think the question is answered in the dialog here, "Tuco must have put out feelers. He's got his ways and means yo, sources."

Comment: @GendoIkari idk cuz when he kidnaps jessie I think he holds him at gunpoint and has him drive him to walt's house.. leading me to believe he did not know where walt lived..

Answer (score 3):

It is never clearly answered, neither in the show nor by Vince or any of the cast, but it *might* be Gus, or someone of his own. Tuco isn't someone who comes off as a sneaky, or a careful, concealed guy, proof being in No-Doze's murder before this AND running his business in without much of a cover. Also, later, someone comes up, knocks on the window (if I remember correctly), and leaves, which in the next frame is "shown" to be Hank... which leads to the question as to why Hank would sneak around a window when he's family?

Plus when Walt meets Gus in *Mandala (S2, E11)*, he is shown to be very calm, composed and very observant, not wanting to meet initially due to seeing Jesse coming in late, and high. So, it might not be too far-fetched that Gus already had tabs on him, through the SUV and the unknown guy on the window (maybe seeing him as a competitor before Saul called), with Walt's high-quality meth moving around. Though, these are speculations and theories at most, because it hasn't been answered formally, and I don't think it will be.